Made for email template options in SharePoint is missing?
I would like to post a news that later will send automated email that broadcast the news that just update in sharepoint. I read about the features that available in SP to be able to do that : Made for email template when you choose to add news. But for my sites, i don't have the options. When click on the news post, i only get the standard template from Microsoft. It is something to do with permission or limitation of version?

Microsoft have updated all News Posts to "Made for Email" by default. So, just try creating a news post using any of the available news/page template and check "Send as email" option is available for you on that page or not. It should be available by default. Let me know if this works for you.
